# Need to split data into multiple columns based on character length of each row, using Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1.head(1)
              Airline_data
0 CAK ATL 114.47 528 424.56 FL 70.19 ...
```

The above column named "Airline_data" contains all information combined into a single column.

This  has to be splitted to multiple columns like ("City1","City2","Average Fare", ... etc )based on the to below information of String index positional splitting

Column name            :               Section of original column to be split

City1                  :                1-3

City2                  :                5-7

Average Fare           :                11-17

and so on.

PLEASE NOTE: Simply splitting based on blank spaces wont work here.

Comment: looks like you'll need to preprocess your csv, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the most intuitive way is to apply *str.extract* to the column of interest
(in your case *0*).

In order to have proper output column names, use named capturing groups
of respective sizes.
To capture the "wanted" fields, put between them either a space or a dot
(matching any char) with respective repetition count.

So for your example 3 columns, run:

```
df[0].str.extract(r'(?P<City1>.{3}) (?P<City2>.{3}) {3}(?P<Average_Fare>.{7})')
```

Note: The name of a named capturing group can not include any spaces,
so I put "_" instead. If you want to get rid of these underscores,
just rename respective columns.

In the final version, to capture all remaining columns, add respective
other capturing groups to the regex above.

Or, if you have the source as a **text file**, then read it calling
*read_fwf*. It reads just **fixed witdh fields** (for details look
the documentation).

This variant is even better in one detail: *read_fwf* by default performs
conversion of input columns to appropriate types (e.g. *int* or *float*),
whereas *str.extract* generates just **text** columns (if you need,
you have to cast the required columns to the intended types on your own.